# Python/Django: What mode for mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to Python and plan to learn Python/Django. I am in the middle of installing Apache and mod_wsgi right now, I have read on the website that there are two modes: `embedded mode` (favoring performance) and `deamon mode` (favoring security). I am wondering what would be a better option in this case, and what is the reasoning behind that? Is there any considerable drawbacks/trade-offs favoring one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [modwsgi documenation](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) explains the differences. *Embedded mode* will run the application within the Apache process itself, *deamon mode* will not. The summary of the first seven paragraphs of the docs:

> Thus, unless you are adept at configuring Apache, always use daemon mode when available.